# hashtable key-value pair comparison to find out unique pair

Tags: java, comparison, hashtable

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Hashtable<String, String> ht1= new Hashtable<>();
ht1.put("10", ghu");
ht1.put("20", "lo");


Hashtable<String, String> ht2= new Hashtable<>();
ht2.put("10", "ko");
ht2.put("20", "lo");
```

how can i compare both hash table by using key-value pair to each other find unique entry of key-value pair from both hash table..

expected output...
("10", "ghu"); this is from first hashtable
("10", "ko"); this is from second hashtable

Answer (score 0):

HashTable keeps an Entry which can get extracted by using getEntrySet() method.
Thus you should something like pseudoCode below. You might need to make some change to below snippet to make it compilable.

```
Set<Entry> entrySet= ht1.getEntrySet();//get all values
      //iterate over those
      for(Entry entry :entrySet ){
            String htVal = ht2.get(entry.getKey());
             if (htval!=null && htVal.equals(entry.getValue())){
                //non unique -ignore
                   }else{
                //store ht1 and ht2 unique entries
                  }
              }
```

Comment: actually i want to compare ht1 entry set to ht2 entry set of not matching then need to store in 3rd hashtable

Comment: you can store the non matching key values pairs of both hashMaps in the else block. My IDE is not installed in current laptop hence I put in the pseudocode instead of complete code. Apologies for that.